# Does the expression $\lceil n/2^{h+1} \rceil$ refer to the number of nodes at a specific level in the context of max-heap?

Tags: algorithms

Exercise 6.3–3 of "Thomas H. Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson, Ronald L. Rivest and Clifford Stein. Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd Edition. The MIT Press, 2009" asks about a proof for

> there are at most $\lceil n/2^{h+1} \rceil$ nodes of height h in any n-element heap.

For the heap in Figure 6.1, there are 10 elements, so n = 10.

Does h refer to the depth? For example, the level pointed out by the red rectangle is at depth=2, so h=2 there, is my understanding correct?

consider all the nodes at depth=2, there are 4 of them in total.

However, the expression from Exercise 6.3–3 would evaluate

$\lceil 10/2^{2+1} \rceil = \lceil 10/8 \rceil = 2$

[image]

which is less than the actual number of nodes at depth=2.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s a difference between depth and height.  Depth is the distance downwards from the root; height is the longest distance upwards from a leaf.

In your example picture,

- the leaves 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 have height 0;
- nodes 3, 4, 5 have height 1;
- node 2 has height 2;
- the root 1 has height 3.

Comment: Thank you. The answer is quite helpful, stackexchange doesn't allow I give the bounty till 10 hours later, so I will check it then.